# Create a generic array accesing a single particular type

Tags: java, arrays, generics, casting, arraylist

I want to convert an `ArrayList` of a generic type to an array of generic types(the same generic type). For exaple I have `ArrayList<MyGeneric<TheType>>` and I want to obtain `MyGeneric<TheType>[]`.

I tried using the `toArray` method and casting:

```
(MyGeneric<TheType>[]) theArrayList.toArray()
```

But this does not work. My other option is to create an array of `MyGeneric<TheType>` and insert one by one the elements of the arraylist, casting them to the correct type.
But Everything I tried to create this array failed.

I know I have to use `Array.newInstance(theClass, theSize)` but how do I obtain the class of `MyGeneric<TheType>`? Using this:

```
Class<MyGeneric<TheType>> test = (new MyGeneric<TheType>()).getClass();
```

Does not work. The IDE states that `Class<MyGeneric<TheType>>` and `Class<? extends MyGeneric>` are incompatible types.

Doing this:

```
    Class<? extends MyGeneric> test = (new MyGeneric<TheType>()).getClass();

    MyGeneric[] data = (MyGeneric[]) Array.newInstance(test, theSize);

    for (int i=0; i < theSize; i++) {
        data[i] = theArrayList.get(i);
    }
    return data;
```

Raises a `ClassCastException` at the line `data[i] = ...`.

What should I do?

Note:

I need the array because I have to use it with a third-party library so "use a insert-the-name-of-the-collection-here" is *not* an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of your type first, then you should call:

> ```
> <T> T[]   toArray(T[] a)
> ```
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the
>   returned array is that of the specified array.

Read the specification:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

If your array is shorter than the list, a new array will be allocated and returned by the method; if your array is longer than the list, the rest items in the array will be set to null.

----------- example ----------

```
ArrayList<MyGeneric<TheType>> list;
//......
MyGeneric<TheType>[] returnedArray = new MyGeneric[list.size()]; // You can't create a generic array. A warning for an error. Don't mind, you can suppress it or just ignore it.
returnedArray = list.toArray(returnedArray); // Cong! You got the MyGeneric<TheType>[] array with all the elements in the list.
```

Comment: What does it mean "create an array of your type first"? Given that I have `ArrayList<MyGeneric<TheType>>` Should `T` be `TheType` or `MyGeneric`? Could you show an example of usage because I don't understand how that method works.

Comment: @Bakuriu T should be MyGeneric<TheType>

Comment: you could also do `new MyGeneric<?>[list.size()]` to avoid using raw types